# How can i make command run X times (discord.js)?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I want to run my lofi.js file X times for my discord bot

I want to make the command run X times, so people can !playlist then [x songs]
x = how many songs they wanna hear from the playlist

what should I add to make it happen?

thank u!

Comment: Execute it X times. `Command.execue()`

Comment: where do I put my number of times (X)? Elitezen

Comment: You can create a loop that runs X times, execute inside the loop

Answer (score 3):

You can create a loop that will run X times, then execute the command inside the loop.

```js
const executeTimes = 5; // Or any other value

for (let i = 0; i < executeTimes; i++) {
   <Command>.execute(...);
}
```

Comment: Sry for my bad knowledge in this but I tried the command and than I got an error reply: 
       <Command>.execute(...);
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: `<Command>.execute()` is pseudo code/placeholder code Since I don't know what your exact code looks like. Replace `<Command>` with your command object and execute it the same way you normally do